# R - calculating mean of every 3 values in array using a for loop

Tags: arrays, r, for-loop

Very new to programming - I have an array with dimension 821 and I would like to take the average of every 3 values. Each line represents monthly data and I need the quarterly averages (so every 3 months). I want to do it using for loops for practice but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: array with dimension 821 means 1 column, 821 rows? and you need mean(1st, 2nd, 3rd value), mean(2nd, 3rd, 4th value) and so on?

Comment: yea, 1 column with 821 rows worth of monthly data. But I need mean(1st, 2nd, 3rd), mean(4th, 5th, 6th), etc. So the first calculation would be the average of the 1st quarter in a year, the 2nd calculation would be the 2nd quarter and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Explanations in the comments.

```
# Create some dummy data. I created one with 822 values instead of 821 because 821 is not divisible without remainder by 3.
vec.dummy <- sample(1:100, 822, replace = TRUE)

# Use the values and create a matrix with 3 columns.
mat.dummy <- matrix(vec.dummy, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)

# Take the row means of each row.
rowMeans(mat.dummy)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using for loops in R if the problem doesn't require it. Keep chugging away and you'll eventually run into a problem that requires it. This one doesn't.

Here's another approach using plyr:

```
    library(plyr)

    array <- rnorm(821) #The array you want to average

    div <- 822/3 #Need an integer number of dividers

    position <- rep(1:div, each=3) 

    data <- data.frame(
            "array"=array,
            "position"=position[1:(length(position)-1)]
           )

    head(data)

             array position
    1 -0.005807528        1
    2  0.997539073        1
    3  1.172736615        1
    4  0.371252122        2
    5  1.291737080        2
    6  0.796526756        2

    #use plyr to average "array" by common values in other column of DF
    data <- ddply(data, c("array"), numcolwise(mean))

    head(data)

          array position
    1 -3.269147      258
    2 -3.076415      158
    3 -2.962204      242
    4 -2.679143       19
    5 -2.306075      231
    6 -2.283344      223
```

Having the second column allows you to keep track of the unique values in your vector. It could be the quarters of your data.

Comment: if I want to specifically solve this using a for loop, how could I go about doing that ?

Comment: @Cam23 check my second answer.

Answer (score 0):

As requested by @Cam23 here is a solution in loop form which I don't recommend:

```
array <- rnorm(821) 

div <- 822/3 

threes <- c(0, 3*(1:(div-1)))

finalArray <- numeric()

for(i in 1:length(threes)){
  calculation <- mean(array[threes[i]+1:3])
  finalArray <- c(finalArray, calculation)
}

finalArray[274] <- mean(array[820:821])
```

The last line is a janky fix due to the fact that 821 isn't nicely divisible by 3.